# html css menu visibility hide by permissions

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I would like use an html/css menu and hide menu items based on users permissions/rights. What would be the best way to handle this? Can it be done just using CSS/HTML or using scripting like Javascript.

The permissions are through "allow roles" subfolders with web.config authorizations. So users cannot go to the wrong page but I want to hide the choices they can't actually access.

I am using VB.net code behind FYI.

Comment: You can do the visibility toggle at client-side. But it would be best to not to serve those items from the server itself. As any guy like you can play with client-side technologies and get to those areas. You should check for the role of a user and only then render a particular page/view for him from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in static CSS/HTML, but you could print different CSS statements for each role if you dynamically generate it.

Or you could assign class 'admin' to certain items, set to display:none in CSS then use jQuery to show them:

```
if(userIsAdmin)
{
    $('.admin').show();
}
```

However, I prefer to do this server-side if possible and only print certain items for certain users because, as Yoda said, anyone can see the source if you do it client side.